# How can i check if a condition is met before a schema field value is set from enum in mongoose schema?

Tags: mongoose

I am working on mongoose. I have a project schema which has two fields type (two enum values) and members which is an array. Type can be 1 when the number of members are greater than 1 and type can be two when the number of members is equal to 1.

How can I set this condition?

Comment: Fixed spellings

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to set field `type` to be `1` when length of field `members` (which is an array) are greater than 1 and `type` to be `2` when length of field `members` is 1. This means you want to store a field whose value is 'state' of another field. I don't recommend this way. You totally can get `type` by using `members.length`. You will see the future problem when you modify `members` (like adding or removing element from array) that affects number of `members` and you have to manually update `type` by yourself. Hope this answer helps you!